# Problems debugging web role remote on Microsoft Azure

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2013

[image]

I am trying to debug a webservice remote on Microsoft Azure. The service is running in a web role.

I have configured remote debugging in the publish settings an can attach the debugger to the web role. Also, when I have selected the correct process, the debug symbols are loaded correctly and breakpoint's tool tips say that the breakpoint is hosted in "WallSHost.exe" which is the remote process.

What I would like to do, is to run a local client software which I am developing and step into the server code from there. When I step into the according service client call (F11), I get the above error message, saying (for the sake of Google in plain text here):

> Unable to automatically step into server. Connecting to the server
>   machine 'xyz.cloudapp.net' failed. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote
>   Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the
>   remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing
>   communication to the remote computer.

I have tried to disable the firewall on my (the client) machine with no effect. Has anybody seen that before or can tell me how fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A quick checklist

- deployed cloud service is a debug build
- a debug build is selected from Build Configuration list (in publish wizard)
- 'Enable Remote Debugger For All Roles' is checked
- no changes to code since deployment

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you very much! I am currently using a Release build, so I'll try and let you know if it worked! Thank you!